# Iterate over recursive struct with recursion function

Tags: go

I have the following struct

```golang
    type Sitemap struct {
        XMLName        xml.Name `xml:"urlset"`
        Namespace      string   `xml:"xmlns,attr"`
        Schema         string   `xml:"xmlns:xsi,attr"`
        SchemaLocation string   `xml:"xsi:schemaLocation,attr"`
        Root           *URLItem
    }

    type URLItem struct {
        XMLName xml.Name `xml:"url"`
        Loc     string   `xml:"loc"`
        LastMod string   `xml:"lastmod,omitempty"`
        Urls    []*URLItem
    }

    func (s *Sitemap) AddURL(key string, url string) {
        node, found := findURLItemRecursive(s.Root, key)
        if found {
            node.Urls = append(node.Urls, &URLItem{Loc: url})
        }
    }


    func findURLItemRecursive(urlItem *URLItem, key string) (*URLItem, bool) {
        if urlItem.Loc == key {
            return urlItem, true
        }

        for _, urlItem := range urlItem.Urls {
            return findURLItemRecursive(urlItem, key)
        }

        return nil, false
    }
```

where the `key` is the parent URL and `url` is the child URL that is linked to the parent for the fact that the children it is found on the page of the parent.

For some unknown reasons `findURLItemRecursive` is buggy.

The issue is that I can't attach more `UrlItem`(s) at the second level.

I mean I can create the `Root` item create the `Urls` slices for the `Root` item but then I can't create nested slices. So I can't go more than the first level.

I'm wondering if the function `findURLItemRecursive` has any obvious bugs in Go that I can't spot.

Comment: The issue is that you are `return` from the loop, it causes your function to return immediately and doesn't traverse the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for you.

```
    type Sitemap struct {
        XMLName        xml.Name `xml:"urlset"`
        Namespace      string   `xml:"xmlns,attr"`
        Schema         string   `xml:"xmlns:xsi,attr"`
        SchemaLocation string   `xml:"xsi:schemaLocation,attr"`
        Root           *URLItem
    }

    type URLItem struct {
        XMLName xml.Name `xml:"url"`
        Loc     string   `xml:"loc"`
        LastMod string   `xml:"lastmod,omitempty"`
        Urls    []*URLItem
    }

    func (s *Sitemap) AddURL(key string, url string) {
        node, found := findURLItemRecursive(s.Root, key)
        if found {
            node.Urls = append(node.Urls, &URLItem{Loc: url})
        }
    }


    func findURLItemRecursive(urlItem *URLItem, key string) (*URLItem, bool) {
        if urlItem.Loc == key {
            return urlItem, true
        }

        for _, urlItem := range urlItem.Urls {
            item, found := findURLItemRecursive(urlItem, key)
            if found {
                return item, found
            }
        }

        return nil, false
    }
```